# How to debug magolia blossom module application from eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, magnolia

I developed magnolia blossom module application by following the link in this [wiki](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Getting+started+with+Blossom). 
I just created a sample template and sample components and deployed in to my webapp.How to debug my application using eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the question is more related on how you debug a Java Webapp in Eclipse. 
If you haven't added Tomcat server in Eclipse you can do it going to Windows -> Show View -> Servers. Then in the servers view, right click and add new, select the Tomcat version you have downloaded in your machine, and set the Tomcat folder as the folder where you have downloaded Tomcat.
Once you have set up the server go back to the Server view, right click on the new server you have just created, select Add/Remove, add your webapp, right click again on the server and select debug and the server with your webapp will be started and then you can place breakpoints in your code. 
You will find some instructions [here](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/1.5/tutorials/InstallTomcat/InstallTomcat.html)

Comment: Hi daniele If it is a normal java web-app what you said is correct, but i am creating a magnolia blossom module where my .java files is placed after that generating a jar for that blossom module and then it will be placed into magnolia webapp lib folder then how to debug my java class in magnolia webapp.

Comment: you do not have to place any jar file anywhere, but you should use maven projects and import the dependencies in your pom.xml in the web app. Follow the instructions in this video https://academy.magnolia-cms.com/display/MA/1+CE+setup+video+tutorial

Comment: you are welcome, and if you can accept my answers here and in your other posts it would be great :)